# R sapply and mean for more than 1 column in split dataframe

Tags: r, mean, sapply

I have a problem concerning sapply in R:
I hav a dataframe Test_ALL that I split by (at the moment) one column named activity. The dataframe has somewhat 20 columns with extra long names ( e.g. fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-std()) that I don`t want to write down explicitely. From this dataframe I want to get a mean for each column. I tried this and it worked for 1 named column.

```
 aa<-split(Test_ALL,Test_ALL$activity)
 y<-sapply(aa,function(x) colMeans(x [c("fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-std()")]))
```

but when I tried to get a mean for more than 1 column it didn`t work.

```
 aa<-split(Test_ALL,Test_ALL$activity)
 y<-sapply(aa,function(x) colMeans(x [c("fBodyBodyGyroJerkMag-std()","fBodyAccMag-std()")]))
```

I tried this too, but also no success

```
namesERG<-names(Test_ALL)
aa<-split(Test_ALL,Test_ALL$activity)
y<-sapply(aa,function(x) colMeans(x[c(namesERG)]))
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thak you!

Comment: Wouldn't `sapply(aa,function(x) colMeans(x[-1])` work for all columns? - You didn't provide data so I can't check

Comment: What is the output? What are you expecting? Have you tried `aggregate`? Something along the lines of `aggregate(. ~ activity, data = Test_ALL)`.

Comment: I tried Sotos proposal but I get this error : Error in colMeans(x[-1]) : 'x' must be numeric --- Test_ALL is a dataFrame, Test_ALL[1,1] for example is numeric, aa is a list

Comment: aggregate did not work either:  Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) :   argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: Your split/sapply code seems to work on some quick test data I wrote up. You should consider writing a reproducible example and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example is difficult to completely understand your problem. Anyway I think that a part of the issue is related to the fact that you have some non numeric columns. I think that somenthing like that could be a solution

```
library(dplyr)
aa <- split(Test_ALL, Test_ALL$activity)
y <- sapply(aa, function(x) colMeans(select_if(x, is.numeric)))
```